# Single image to video in c#

Tags: c#, image, video, aforge

I've been using Aforge in VS to manipulate images, and now I need to convert a single image to video. The code I have works, but as soon as I add an image path it outputs an empty video. I guess is something very simple, but since i know practicly nothing about c#, I need help every step of the process.

Can someone please help me with this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge;
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;


namespace VideoWriter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int width = 720;
            int height = 402;

            VideoFileWriter writer = new VideoFileWriter();
            writer.Open(@"C:\pathtovideo\video.mp4", width, height, 25, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 1000000);

            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(width, height);

            // THIS ONE NEXT IS WHAT I HAVE BEEN TRYING, BUT I GUESS IS VERY WRONG
            //Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"C:\pathtoimage\myimage.jpg");

            for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteVideoFrame(image);
            }

            writer.Close();

        }
    }
```

By the way, any other solution not including libraries or frameworks is wellcome. I am just using Aforge because is the easiest way, I believe.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to create a video from a JPEG image with the following code:

```
int width = 720;
int height = 402;

VideoFileWriter writer = new VideoFileWriter();
writer.Open(@"C:\Temp\video.mp4", width, height, 25, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 1000000);

Bitmap originalImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\Temp\myimage.jpg");
Bitmap resizedImage = new Bitmap(originalImage, new Size(width, height));

for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
{
    writer.WriteVideoFrame(resizedImage);
}

writer.Close();
```

You'll need to resize the image to match to size of the video frame.

Comment: God bless you sly! 

This would have been my third attempt with out answer. So I will be trying this code today and I will back here to let you and everyone know what happened. 

Thanks a lot again!

Comment: By the way sly,

Do you know how to manipulate the quality of the video that is being generated? It lost a lot of quality from the image! Thanks again!

Comment: Perhaps just increasing the "1000000" number, correct?

Comment: That's right, the bit rate affects the quality of the video. See [VideoFileWriter.Open Method](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/51f9e309-8412-0bff-2f93-99b213bc2a57.htm). You can also just not set that parameter and I believe it will use the highest bit rate: `writer.Open(@"C:\Temp\video.mp4", width, height, 25, VideoCodec.MPEG4);`

Comment: Oh! I see. Thanks for everything again, Sly!